# Clear command from terminal in OS X

Tags: macos, terminal

Say I've typed out a command in terminal 'mv *.jpg ..\photos' and as I'm typing realize I no longer want to execute this command at all. I want to just delete the entire statement. I don't want to clear the entire screen or delete any bash history I just want to abort the current line and erase it.

Is there a keyboard shortcut or do I have to actually delete each character?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Assuming you're in bash, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks! that did it. Is there a format list of keyboard shortcuts documented somewhere?

Comment: http://www.ice2o.com/bash_quick_ref.html

Comment: This worked for me in zshell too.

Comment: This only works if your cursor is at the END of the line. For those situations where your cursor is at the beginning you need to use CTRL-K

Comment: How do you cause this in a script?

Answer (score 8):

Many programs that wait for you to type a command line and then execute that line, including bash, take <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to mean “Abort the current task and go back to the main prompt”.

A few programs, including bash, take <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>([Clear command from terminal in OS X](https://superuser.com/questions/192490/clear-command-from-terminal-in-os-x/192492#192492)) to mean “erase the beginning of the line, up to the cursor” (or “erase the whole line”).

In bash, observable differences between <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> include:

- You can undo <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>, but not <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> retains the part of the line after the cursor, if any.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> erases the affected text from the screen; <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> shows a new prompt below the current line.

Sometimes you want to stop typing a command but enter it in the shell history to run later. A useful trick is to put a `#` at the beginning of the line and execute it: since the line is now a comment, it won't do anything. In bash, there is a single-key shortcut: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>#</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

There is a `readline` function that is probably not bound to a keystroke called `kill-whole-line` that will kill the whole line as opposed to only killing the part before the cursor (`unix-line-discard` which is somewhat of a misnomer and is bound to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>u</kbd>).

You can bind that to any available keystroke. I like <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>U</kbd> since it's a related function. That keystroke may be bound to `do-lowercase-version` which means it does whatever the unshifted version does (in this case `upcase-word`). Since we don't really need two keys to do that, let's use that one.

You can try it out at the command line by creating the binding this way:

```
bind '"\eU":kill-whole-line'
```

or make it persistent by putting this line in your `~/.inputrc` file:

```
"\eU":kill-whole-line
```

To undo a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>u</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>U</kbd> (or any operation that can be undone), press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>_</kbd> (underscore) or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>u</kbd> (two keystrokes). Or you can paste back in (yank) what you killed by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>y</kbd> which can be repeated if you want multiple copies of that text.

By the way, if you want to kill text from the cursor to the end of the line, you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>k</kbd>. So instead of doing the binding described above, you can kill a whole line by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>u</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>k</kbd>. Only the part killed by the second of those keystrokes will be saved in the kill buffer, but you can still do undo twice to recover them both.